# Modules over monoids vs algebra over monads

Tags: category-theory, modules, definition, monoid, monads

I read somewhere that the construction of algebras over monads is motivated by/ similar to the construction of modules over monoids, but I'm having difficulty seeing this.
I see that a monad "looks like" a monoid ( it has multiplication and a unit and satisfies associativity and unit axioms), but beyond that the comparison seems a bit opaque to me.
Can anyone shed light on this? Thanks!

Comment: A monad is a monoid in an endofunctor category. A module for a monad viewed as a monoid is an algebra for that monad (though modules for monads are more general). See [this nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad#Algebras) for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monoid actions for a fixed monoid $M$ are an *instance* of being algebras for a monad.

Specifically, let the monad be $T:\mathcal{Set}\to\mathcal{Set},\ X\mapsto M\times X$ (which is, by the way, the underlying set of the *free* $M$-module generated by $X$), with monad multiplication induced by the monoid multiplication: $X\times M\times M\to X\times M$ and monad unit induced by the monoid unit $X\to X\times M,\ x\mapsto (x,1_M)$.